# CodeIgniter handle URL segments

Tags: codeigniter, url, segment

I keep thinking about how to deal with URLs and pages with CI but I can't think to a good way to do this.

I'm trying to handle url like this:

```
site.com/shop (shop is my controller)
site.com/shop/3 (page 3)
site.com/shop/cat/4 (categorie and page 4)
site.com/shop/cat/subcat/3 (cat & subcat & page)
```

Is there any good way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create controller functions to handle:

- *shop* and shop *pages*
- *categories* and category *pages*
- *subcategories* and subcategory *pages*

**Controller functions**

In your `shop` controller you could have the following functions:

```
function index($page = NULL)
{
    if ($page === NULL)
    {
        //load default shop page
    }
    else  //check if $page is number (valid parameter)
    {
        //load shop page supplied as parameter
    }
}

function category($category = NULL, $page = 1)
{
    //$page is page number to be displayed, default 1
    //don't trust the values in the URL, so validate them
}

function subcategory($category = NULL, $subcategory = NULL, $page = 1)
{
    //$page is page number to be displayed, default 1
    //don't trust the values in the URL, so validate them
}
```

**Routing**

You could then setup the following [routes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) in `application/config/routes.php`. These routes will map the URLs to the appropriate controller functions. The regex will allow look for values

```
//you may want to change the regex, depending on what category values are allowed

//Example: site.com/shop/1    
$route['shop/(:num)'] = "shop/index/$1";   

//Example: site.com/shop/electronics  
$route['shop/([a-z]+)'] = "shop/category/$1";

//Example: site.com/shop/electronics/2 
$route['shop/([a-z]+)/(:num)'] = "shop/category/$1/$2";

//Example: site.com/shop/electronics/computers
$route['shop/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)'] = "shop/subcategory/$1/$2";

//Example: site.com/shop/electronics/computers/4 
$route['shop/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(:num)'] = "shop/subcategory/$1/$2/$3";
```

Comment: in the subcategory function... how can I know the cat name ?

Comment: @fred.kassi do you want _category_, _subcategory_ and _page_ all to be parameters?

Comment: I think so... site.com/shop/smartphone/apple or site.com/shop/smartphone/34 or site.com/shop/54/

Comment: Ok, I think my answer will now do what you want?

Comment: No problem, I'm pleased that my answer helped!

Comment: :) ... and about the index function => index function($page = 1) isn't it better ?

Comment: Could be! It depends on what you want to load by default. If you want to load the first page, then `$page = 1` would be best; if, for example, you want some sort of 'landing page' then `$page = NULL` may be more suitable.